# Complimentary Shaders with the M1 chip

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, macos, minecraft-shader

Details:

- I am using the M1 chip from Apple
- My hardware is the macOS Monterey
- Using Mac version 12.2 beta

Problem:

Every time I try to load MC (any version) with shaders such as, BSL or Complimentary shaders Minecraft crashes. Some shaders do work, like Sildurs and Toaster shaders but I would like to know how to fix this.

Note:
If I go on the homepage, and click "options" from there, and *then* put the shaders, it doesn't crash. But after doing that and loading a world it crashes

Comment: This seems like technical support for mods.

Comment: @Topcode what do you mean?

Comment: Well technical support for mods is off topic here, the best place for that is with the mod creators.

Comment: do you know where i can contact the mod creators?

Comment: Well assuming you are using optifine for shaders that would be optifine.net